# Static variable set to null available for GC?

Tags: java, static

When I set a static variable to null, will be available for GC ?

static Integer jfv;

```
boolean someMethod(){

jfv =10;
//use for some purpose

jfv = null
return true;
}
```

In this case, will jfv be picked by GC ?

Edit:

There was typo, the question was is static object available for GC after assigning  null values.

Thanks for all the responses

Comment: this code doesn't compile at all in the first place. Don't know how you got to that.

Comment: I just created the snippet on the  fly to explain the problem and in the process created an error. However, someone managed to answer it for me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot assign null to an `int` variable.

But what you are trying to do is wrong-headed anyway.

The `int` type is a primitive type ... and that means that `int` variables not ever have an independent existence in the Java heap.  Hence there is nothing to be garbage collected.

Now if `jfv` was a reference type (i.e. its type was a class or an array type), then assigning `null` to it:

- would be legal, and
- *may* result in the object that `jfv` refers to being a candidate for garbage collection.

Note that the last bullet is qualified:

- If the object that `jfv` refers to is *reachable* from other places, then it won't be a candidate for garbage collection.
- The fact that something is a *candidate* for garbage collection doesn't mean that it *will* be garbage collected.  It depends when the collector is run ... and some other things.

---

Finally, it is generally a bad idea to try to influence / control when Java objects are garbage collected.  Just let the garbage collector deal with it.  There are some exceptions to this; read about Java memory leaks.

Incorrect use of `static` variables is a common cause of memory leaks ... but randomly assigning `null` to statics is not the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. The typo in the snippet made it look like a stupid question

Answer (score 3):

What `jvf` *used* to contain would be available for reclamation, but not its current value.
That is, if an `int` were an object, which it isn't.

Comment: +1. Not that you can set an `int` field to `null` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The null to int was a typo. I was trying to get create a scenario ! Thanks !